# MySQL FULLTEXT cant find index

Tags: mysql, full-text-search, fulltext-index

I try to run the following query

```
SELECT * FROM complains WHERE match(title, description) against('+lorem' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
```

Table complains has two FULLTEXT indexes. title and description but I still get this error from MySQL

```
Error Code: 1191. Can't find FULLTEXT index matching the column list
```

However I can run the query for each row on its own

```
SELECT * FROM complains WHERE match(description) against('+lorem' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
SELECT * FROM complains WHERE match(title) against('+lorem' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
```

This works fine. What I am missing?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you are listing multiple fields in the `match()` operator and use Boolean mode and innodb table engine, then you need to have a multi-column fulltext index in place that covers the fields, as MySQL documentation on [Boolean Full-Text Searches](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/fulltext-boolean.html) says:

> InnoDB tables require a FULLTEXT index on all columns of the MATCH() expression to perform boolean queries. Boolean queries against a MyISAM search index can work even without a FULLTEXT index, although a search executed in this fashion would be quite slow.